# Add records using Entity Framework CF migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a table A and a table B with the following relationship:

Table A

```
Id
...
```

Table B

```
Id
TableA_Id  (foreign key table A)
```

I am using Entity Framework code first and have activated migrations.

**What I want to do is to make a migration that adds a record in Table A for every exising record of Table B, and then add a foreign key reference to the new Table A row in Table B.**

I have used the following command and created an empty migration:

```
Add-Migration <NameOfMyMigration>
```

This resulted in the following code:

```
public partial class NameOfMyMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        // This is where I want to write code that adds records
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: In old good days something like that would be done by a trigger. just saying

Comment: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/ (you can seed from migration configuration class)

Comment: Thanks! I added some code in my seed class that adds the records as required. However in order to get the migration to trigger the seed logic, I had to make the Up-method add and drop a dummy column, otherwise the seed code would not run. This doesnt strike me as an awesome solution... Any better ways to achieve this? :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understand what you need, but i think your situation is that you have already Code First Project and already have database full of data and now you want to add new table so first i tried to reach out your situation :

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ClassB> BList { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

    }
    public class ClassB
    {
        public ClassB()
        {
            BId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        }
         [Key]
        public string BId { get; set; }


    }
```

and in the seed method :

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        context.BList.AddOrUpdate(

          new ClassB { BId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
          new ClassB { BId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
          new ClassB { BId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
        );

    }
```

then Add-Migration  
and update-database
now i have a table called ClassBs with 3 rows
then create ClassAs Table :

```
public class ClassA
    {
        public ClassA()
        {
            AId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        }
        [Key]
        public string AId { get; set; }


    }
```

and add DbSet like before to the Context:

```
public DbSet<ClassA> AList { get; set; }
```

and in the seed method :

```
    context.AList.AddOrUpdate(

      new ClassA { AId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
      new ClassA { AId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
      new ClassA { AId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
    );
```

now i have two tables with one-to-many relation  just like you have
finally i can now edit the ClassB table row by row  . 
 the seed method :

```
 protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //

        var BArray = context.BList.ToArray();
        var AArray = context.AList.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < BArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (BArray.Length == AArray.Length)
            {
                BArray[i].AID = AArray[i].AId;

            }

        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

now  just update-database
it works .

Comment: No, both tables already exist, as does the relationship between them. The only thing that is new, is that there now MUST be a correlating row in TableA, which was previously not a requirement. Therefore I need a proper way to seed data without introducing any model changes. I found a solution (see my own answer) but it's more of a hack than a proper solution in my book

Comment: You do not need any model changes to seed data all you need to do just write your code in the seed method then just excute update-database .

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question comments from Alexander Derck I ended up with the following solution. I'll post it here in case anyone else needs a solution to this.

**However, I personally think this is more of a hack than a solution, therefore I am still interested in a proper way to solve this. Do not copy-paste this answer into your production environment without questioning its validity!**

The solution is to add some code in the seed configuration. Follow [this link](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) for more info (copied from Alexander Derck's comment)

The seed code is along the lines of this:

```
foreach (var tableBData in context.TableB.ToList())
{
    if (tableB.TableA == null)
    {
        var tableA = new TableA();
        tableB.TableB = tableA;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then the shady stuff: The following is an excerpt from the referenced blog entry:

> [the migration seed] runs whenever the Update-Database PowerShell command is executed.
>   Unless the Migrations initializer is being used the Migrations Seed
>   method will not be executed when your application starts.

In order to trigger the migration (which is empty by default, i.e. it does not contain any actual modifications) I added the following code in my migration logic:

```
public partial class NameOfMyMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.TableA", "DummyField", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
        DropColumn("dbo.TableA", "DummyField");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Of course this migration is only required in case this is the **last** migration before a new release, because any migration following this one would also trigger the seed, thus negating the need for this.

I still feel that there must be a better way to solve this, though?

Answer (score 0):

Use Automatic Migrations.

Follow the instructions from this MSDN Blog post. [Automatic Migrations Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735)

First you need to enable the automatic migrations.  In the PM console, run   `Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations`

Once enabled you can use the commands `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` to do all the heavy lifting for you.

This will scaffold your up and down methods automatically and add the records to the database.

**EDIT:** Updated link to current version.

Comment: Although correct, it is pretty clearly stated in the question that migrations is already set up, and that I did run an Add-Migration command to create an empty migration (because there are no model changes involved)

Comment: Yes but there is a difference between the 'manual' migrations and automatic-migrations.  Enable Automatic Migrations to be able to use this solution.

Comment: I fail to see how automatic migrations could assist me with popuplating existing tables with new data

Comment: Hi @havardhu, I reread your question, I believe you are asking how to automate a process to add rows in TableA that have a forgien key to TableB.  Is this correct?